# How to invoke elastic search the url with particular index in api hit

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-elasticsearch

I have created `test-index` using `aws-lambda-python`

I have created api, i need to invoke the url with the above index name `test-index`
which is having index pattern below

`result = es.search(index="my-index-1", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})`

How get the content in result on hitting one URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import boto3
import json
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_id, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://xx.amazonaws.com'],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    es.cluster.health()
    es.indices.delete(index='data', ignore=[400, 404])

    es.indices.create(index='data', ignore=400)
    r = [{'id': '1', 'data': 'Health'},
 {'id': '2', 'data': 'countries'},
 {'id': '3', 'data': 'currency'},
 {'id': '4', 'data': 'language'}]
    for e in enumerate(r):
        es.index(index="data", body=e[1])
        result = es.search(index="data", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        #'body': json.dumps('API INVOKES!')
        'body':result
    }
```